# bootstrap carousel is not working on node js pug engine

Tags: node.js, pug

```
extends layouts/main-layout.pug

block styles
 link(rel="stylesheet", href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css")

block content 
    script(src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js")
    main                   
        #carouselExampleControls.carousel.slide(data-ride='carousel')
            .carousel-inner
                .carousel-item.active
                    img.d-block.w-100(src='/images/home.png' alt='First slide')
                .carousel-item
                    img.d-block.w-100(src='/images/home1.png' alt='Second slide')
            a.carousel-control-prev(href='#carouselExampleControls' role='button' data-slide='prev')
                span.carousel-control-prev-icon(aria-hidden='true')
                span.sr-only Previous
            a.carousel-control-next(href='#carouselExampleControls' role='button' data-slide='next')
                span.carousel-control-next-icon(aria-hidden='true')
                span.sr-only Next
```

Above is my `.pug` file.
output that I am getting is: home image below this home1 image below that previousnext.

I want to achieve: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/ {With controls}
SS
Add an answer

Comment: bootstrap.js requires jquery. Make sure you include that for the carousel to work.

Comment: Thanks for reply Stephen. yes the issue was jquery was not including properly on page.